# Can i use mouse-click event as a function without human interaction ? So that whenever i call the function, it makes the control clicked

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a ComboBox Control, in which there is dropdown button.
Now I have to open the list without using human interaction by default.

Can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ComboBox.DroppedDown Property:

```
comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick respose but this was just an example. How can i do this in other control ? like button to be pressed automatically without human interaction ?

Comment: Well for buttons at least you can use Button.PerformClick

Comment: Use this code behind any event. You can open the combo box. For example, form load